# HTML line with a downward arrow

Tags: css, html

I am trying to draw a line with a small arrow pointing down as in the image attached.

[image]

I have not been able to get the downward arrow. Is there a way I can do it using html and css?

HTML

```
  <hr class="line">
```

CSS

```
.line{
width:70%;
color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4eL39sm1/

Thanks.

Comment: That's quite a poor attempt, in other words your asking someone to do the dirty work for you... Take a look here, at the last example : http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use pseudo-elements `:after` and `:before`:

```css
.line {
    width:70%;
}
.line:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 7px 0;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 8px;
    left: 45%;
}
.line:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 7px 0;
    border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 9px;
    left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<hr class="line">
```

You can play with `border-width` to adjust the size to your needs.

Comment: I wouldn't wonder if this stop working on contemporary web browsers as `<hr>` is a void element which doesn't contain anything. Just because it is working now, doesn't mean it will work in the future.

Comment: Can't understand what you try to achieve with this comment to be honest.

Comment: I meant it's better not to apply `::after`/`::before` pseudo-elements to the `<hr>` empty tag. If browsers support it at the moment, I'd say that's a bug.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for helping me out. That works fine. I don't mean to question your solution, but I am trying to understand how its working,. Which part in the CSS you provided is rendering the downward arrow?

Comment: As i said pseudo elements `after` and `before` did the trick. I create using this two pseudo`elements two triangles. One white and one gray(for the border). Take also a look here [after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) and [before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before/).