# <hr> line with a arrow in between pointing down

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw a line with a small arrow pointing down as in the image attached.

[image]

I was able to get it working on fiddle using before and after psuedo tags ( with [help from Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345692/html-line-with-a-downward-arrow)).

```
<hr class="line">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4eL39sm1/6/

But I now need it in a div tag like this

```
<div class="hr"></div>
```

I have edited my css accordingly

```
div.hr{
width:70%;
}

div.hr:after {
content:'';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 15px 0;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: 8px;
left: 45%;
}

div.hr:before {
content:'';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 15px 0;
border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: 9px;
left: 45%;
}
```

I made these 2 observations:

1. The arrow part looks a solid triangle.
2. The arrow (triangle was mispalced was up in the top). I removed the top value form css and it aligned well but it still looks like a triangle.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/4eL39sm1/8/ ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can modify to this:

```css
div.hr {
    width:70%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #7F7F7F;
}
div.hr:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 8px;
    left: 35%;
}
div.hr:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
    border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 9px;
    left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr"></div>
```

As you can see you don't have to remove `top` from `pseudo-elements`. The only thing you have to add is `height: 1px` and background color same as the second triangle.

Also if you wan to use it inside another element for example and align to center you can use this:

```css
div.hr {
    width:70%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #7F7F7F;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.hr:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50%;
}
div.hr:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
    border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="hr"></div>
</div>
```

p.s. By the way i was the person who answered in your first post :)

After conversation with @user3861559 i created an approach for his situation. Instead of `pseudo-elements` I use nested divs with the same result:

```css
div.hr {
    width:70%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #7F7F7F;
}
div.after {
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 8px;
    left: 35%;
}
div.before {
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
    border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 9px;
    left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr">
    <div class="before"></div>
    <div class="after"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you two! :) 

Its puzzling to me that it works fine in fiddl ebut I face the same issue in my page. I inspected the element and the before and after CSS values are the same.

Comment: Is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: Describe me what you try to achieve please and why this approach doesn't suits you?

Comment: Hey Alex, sorry for the late response.

The page I am building in is Adobe CQ and this particular 'line with an arrow' is a component. I want to be able to have a default color for the line and also have an option to take user input for the color. Since I can style the psuedo elements inline I will not be able to use this approach although your code snippet suggestion does what exaclty I needed in a static environment.

I'd like to provide link to the page but the page is accessible only to the systems connected to my employer's network.

Comment: No problem but is really hard to help you that way. Don't really know what Adobe CQ is to be honest. Can you describe the issue again please?

Comment: I understand. I was looking for a way to render the image in plain HTML and CSS without using psuedo elements. Thanks anyway for your help! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63439/discussion-between-alex-char-and-user3861559).

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Why not to use sematic HTML and just style `<hr/>`?