# M shaped border with css?

Tags: css

[image: See the attached Image]

I am able to draw the straight line on both sides in two ways, using span tags or before and after pseudo-code. But the problem is the middle part, I have no idea on how to get it done with the help of css. Do not want to include image.

HTML:

```
<span class="simple-border"></span>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<span class="simple-border"></span>
```

Css:

```
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: This is the third time per 7 days ago that I face with questions like this.

Comment: For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472289/hr-line-with-a-arrow-in-between-pointing-down

Comment: you can use this if you don't want to use `:before` or `:after` for adding border http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/0q4ogweq/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Couldn't be much better than this :) Thanks much , you are the man

Answer (score 0):

you need to use :before and :after selectors in your css to create angled borders. this article should get you started....

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/