# Ideas on how to construct this line?

Tags: css, html, css-shapes

Hello Stackoverflow,

I'm new to CSS3 and would like to learn the best ways(according to modern standards) to  build the line in this image.

[image: line]

After several tries, this is the best one I could come up with:
[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/b174p9xL/4/)

How can I add the shadow?

```
Any tips would be appreciated! Have an awesome coding day all :)
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472289/hr-line-with-a-arrow-in-between-pointing-down

Comment: @j08691 That question doesn't have a blending effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic idea for this.

1. You need to have 3 divs in your horizontal div component, let's call
   them left, center, right.
2. left and right divs have a gradient that gives the merge-in effect. You can simply use css gradients in the background for that.
3. Center div needs to have one child element ( or pseudo element ), which has only right and bottom borders set. We now rotate this child
   element by 45deg so it looks like the arrow.
4. You may still have problems because the child element will not be able to hide the line running in the middle for center div. To
   resolve this, you can use 2 more child divs inside center div, which
   are arranged left and right to the rotated div.

Another much easier approach is to use a png background image for your horizontal div component ;).

Answer (score 0):

To do a line with end extremities like that you needa linear gradient. Then you can add the triangle on top afterwards. You should attempt it first and come back if you have problems. Here is the line to start:

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/927Lp5bt/