# <hr> line with a arrow in between pointing up in css

Tags: css

hr or div line with up arrow in between. similar to this ([Down arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472289/hr-line-with-a-arrow-in-between-pointing-down))

I had tried it. Looks like I am not able to move the arrow to correct position.

My Code:

```css
div.hr {
    width:100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #7F7F7F;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:15px;
}
div.hr:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
}
div.hr:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 4px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr"></div>
```

Comment: Eh...what is your question?

Comment: What is your question? Where are your codes.,

Comment: Is it too hard to play with `border-width`? You have the example.

Comment: Some questions have no code included ... you didn't even include a complete sentence...

Comment: Please see my answer and codepen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modified version of the example you provided, with the arrow pointing up, rather than down. Hope this helps.

DEMO: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oexadv)

CSS:

```
div.hr {
    width:100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #7F7F7F;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:15px;
}
div.hr:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -14px;
    left: 50%;
}
div.hr:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hr"></div>
```